# Workflow not getting triggered when rollout occurs in AEM

Tags: aem, launcher, workflow-services

I have a blueprint copy(**C2**) created from the source copy (**C1**) that has the default rollout config.

Also there exist a launcher that triggers the workflow (**W1**) on any modification done on any page hierarchy of **C2**. The workflow purpose is to do some processing and then activate the page.

**So the workflow W1 was being triggered whenever there is rollout from C1 to C2**

**Issue**

Whenever any page is deactivated in **C2** , the page is going to activate state because of the launcher( **since cq:lastReplicationAction being changed from Activate to Deactivate**)

For the above issue I placed a condition in launcher as **cq:lastReplicationAction != Deactivate**. The deactivate issue gets resolved but now the workflow W1 is not being triggered whenever there is a rollout for a page in C1 to a deactivated page in C2.

Although, I tried with possible solutions like adding the rollout config action - **targetActivate** & **workflow** on copy C2 but no luck. Is there any way we can trigger the workflow W1 on rollout ? Please suggest.